# Reading a Text File Line by Line to Make a Map in XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I want to read a text file in order to build map.

For example I have this map:

```
0@0000000
0@0000000
0@0000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
```

I know I should use this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath+@"/TestMap.MMAP");
string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

Now, for example, I want read line 2 char "@". how can i do this?

please help me.

---

**Solved:**

Thank you (@L.B AND @user861114), at last my problem was solved:

```
string[,] item = new string[9, 7];
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + @"/TestMap.MMAP");
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        item[i, j] = line[j].Substring(i, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j + "=" + item[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(your path);
```

then you can access

```
char ch = lines[1][1]; //second line's second char
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's little bit easy :

```
string[] strs = string.split(myString, "\n"); // split to array of string by delimiter     endline
char[] chars = strs[1].ToCharArray(); // you can get second char "@"
```